# Pandas how to squeeze duplicate rows into one row

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
| name    | value |
| name_1  |  A    |
| name_1  |  B    |
| name_1  |  C    |
```

How to reshape dataframe  to looks like

```
| name    | value |
| name_1  | A,B,C |
```

or

```
 | name    | value   |
 | name_1  | [A,B,C] |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby.agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby('name').agg(list)
            value
name             
name_1  [A, B, C]
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> df.groupby('name').agg(', '.join)
          value
name           
name_1  A, B, C
>>>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you !

Comment: @AlexNikitin Great.